# Startup services on Debian 9

Tags: debian, systemd, startup, services, init

I tried to **remove some services from startup** using various software like:

- `bum`
- `sysv-rc-conf`
- `rcconf`

But... some services are still executed, like `MySQL`, `OpenVPN`, `MongoDB` etc.

I wonder if I am missing something, I did not understand what `systemd` is used for. Maybe these software are **deprecated** and should not be used anymore... Therefore, I do not see all services in it, VBox services are load but I cannot see them is these software.

I am just trying to save my battery's life.

Here's a screenshot from `sysv-rc-conf`.

[image]

Comment: Well, `systemd` is what actually manages all daemon processes on your system.  How did you remove services from the startup?  Was it not using `systemd` (`systemctl`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `# systemctl disable <your_service>` to disable it.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. Please mark it as "answered".